# Subscription in router

Tags: meteor

I want to subscribe to data on specific pages, so I put `subscribe()` inside `router.js`. I am not sure if I should enclose it inside `Meteor.isClient()` block. Should I? When will I ever do routing for the server-side?

```
Router.route('/courses/:_id', function () {
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("comments");
  }
  this.render('CourseDetail', { .. });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the `if (Meteor.isClient){}` check inside of your `router.js` file, you can simply remove that check and put the file inside of the top-level `client` folder in your application directory. This way, you do not have to worry about your routes being processed on the server at all. In making that change, you can structure your route definition above in one of two ways:

```
Router.route('/courses/:id', function() {
    this.wait(Meteor.subscribe('comments')); // Either this one
    this.subscribe('comments').wait(); // or this one. DO NOT DO BOTH.

    if(this.ready()) {
        this.render();
    } else {
        this.render('CourseDetail');
    }
});
```

or:

```
Router.route('/courses/:id', {
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe('comments');
    },
    action: function() {
        this.render('CourseDetail');
    }
});
```

Notice that the first option passes a function as the second parameter to the `Router.route()` function while the second option passes an object as the second parameter to the `Router.route()` function. Both options are perfectly valid. For information on the first option, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#subscriptions) out; for information on the second option, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options) out.

As for when you would ever do server-side routing, this is usually done if you are setting up an HTTP request/response part of your application for external applications to access your server. Unless this is the case, you would most likely never need to worry about setting up such a thing. In the case of doing this, however, you would define your routes and put them in the top-level `server` folder in your application directory. for information on server-side routing, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing) out.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the Meteor wrapper. Iron router has its own syntax for saying where you want your route to run.

Here is an example.

```
Router.route('/item', function () { var req = this.request; var res = this.response; res.end('hello from the server\n'); }, {where: 'server'});
```

Here is the docs site.

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

Answer (score 0):

You should define the subscription in the onBeforeAction option of the iron router route.

```
Router.route('/courses/:_id', function () {
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        Meteor.subscribe("comments");
    },
    action: function (){
        this.render('CourseDetail', { .. });
    }
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options)